# Team Foundation Server 2010 Delete SharePoint website

Tags: sharepoint, web

How can I delete sharepoint website from TFS Admin console? Because I delete Team Project Collection but Sharepoints website still exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting the Project / Collection doesn't delete the Sharepoint site. You need to go to the Sharepoint Central Administration page and delete it from there.

There's a [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262392.aspx) article on it.